# Lock screen orientation for a single controller when there's a UITabBar in IOS 5 & 6

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

Following are the main poins I have.

1. I'm new to IOS development
2. I need to support IOS 5 and IOS 6 in my IOS app
3. I have a UITabBarController in AppDeligate file as follows.

   UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[Grid1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Grid1ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[VideoListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideoListViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[MusicViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MusicViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[GalleryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GalleryViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];

   UINavigationController *myNav1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
   UINavigationController *myNav2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    UINavigationController *myNav3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
   UINavigationController *myNav4=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];

   UIImage *navBackgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aa.png"];

   [myNav1.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   [myNav2.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   [myNav3.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   [myNav4.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

   self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
   self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNav1, myNav2, myNav3,myNav4,nil];

4.I want to lock the rotation of every controller which is directly connected to  tabBarController( ex - Grid1ViewController). But I need to rotate the some controller which are used in the app. Please refer the following drawing. A,B,C,D and E are controllers.
[image: rotation of controllers]

5. I tried implementing following method in controllers and AppDeligate file. But didn't work. When rotation are allowed the whole app start to rotate.

   (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

   NSLog(@"5 rotation");
   return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
   }
   // For IOS 6

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   NSLog(@"shouldAutorotate");
   return YES;
   }
   (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   NSLog(@"6 rotation");
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }

How can I achieve this? Please help. Thank you in advance.